# How do I remove all no math symbols from a string android java stuck

Tags: java, android, regex, eclipse, string

How I remove all non-math symbols or numbers from a string.

So I want a string to be able to contain

**+** or **-** or numbers 0-9

But any other symbols or alphabetical characters to be removed.

How do I do this, I've tried the below but that removes, **-** and **+**

```
string.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: It removes - and + since you haven't specified that you want to match them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourString.replaceAll("[^-+\\d]","");
```